# Design help for a networked application?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, casting

**NOTICE**

This is a rather large question, so please bear with me and I apologize in advance if this is unclear. For the sake of making this question manageable, and to minimize confusion, I omit some properties from copy-and-pasted classes.

**CONTEXT**

I'm writing a networked application - a 'remote desktop' sort of application so that the average techie nerd can help his friends or neighbors with computer issues. I realize free and much more advanced software like TeamViewer exists, but this question isn't discussing the practicality of creating this software.

**COMMON TERMS**

The *client* is the techie nerd, the helper - the *controller*. The *server* is the 'victim', the one in distress. The *client* is usually the one to initiate commands to the server.

**INFORMATION**

This software is more than a live view/control application. I wanted extra *modules*, such as a *File Explorer Module*, and a *Chat Module* (*so they could both communicate without needing to use extra instant messaging software*).

Originally, my approach to sending and receiving messages across UDP was manual and inefficient. (*I use the Lidgren library for UDP networking so that's why my packets don't show low-level bytes like a header message size.*)

```
Original Packet Structure:

Byte Index    Type      Purpose/Description
------------------------------------------------------
0             byte      The intended destination module (e.g. 1 -> Chat module)
1             byte      The command for this module to perform (e.g. 0 -> NewChatMessage)
2             byte      Encryption/compression flag
3             byte      Packet priority flag (e.g. Cancel packets should be processed first)
4-X            ?        Command-specific arguments of variable type (e.g. For this example, the argument would be the actual chat message text)
```

This approach became difficult to wrap my head once I head 100+ messages. The source became cryptic and modifications were a chore. Even by coding the 'destination module' and 'command' as an enum (still indirectly numbers), it was still difficult to develop the application. When receiving these packets, parsing the command-specific arguments would become a ridiculously long switch ladder nested inside a ridiculously long if-else ladder.

I later decided to employ serialization for my packet structure. I could now design each command as a class, and then serialize it into a compact byte array (or string), and then de-serialize it back into its original class and read the arguments as class properties. It seemed much easier, and I was willing to pay the cost of bandwidth for the larger serialized data structure.

```
Revised Packet Structure:

Byte Index    Type      Purpose/Description
------------------------------------------------------
0-X           String    Serialized class
```

**THE PROBLEM**

But this question is one of design. I have no problem serializing and de-serializing my classes. The problem lies in how I design my command/packet classes. I find myself stuck doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342547/how-can-i-cast-an-interface-as-its-type-in-c). The designs of my classes are below:

**Packet Base Class**

```
/// <summary>
/// The fundamental unit of network communication which can be transmitted and received from client to server. Contains the destination module and module-specific command.
/// </summary>
public class Packet
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies the module this packet is forwarded to.
    /// </summary>
    public Module DestinationModule { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies whether this packet is encrypted or compressed.
    /// </summary>
    public EncryptionCompressionFlag EncryptedOrCompressed { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies the packet's priority.
    /// </summary>
    public PacketPriority Priority { get; set; }
}
```

**Welcome Module Packet Base (more about this below)**

```
/// <summary>
/// Base packet structure for packets specific to this module. Adds a ModuleCommand property from the base Packet class.
/// </summary>
public class WelcomeModulePacket : Packet
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies the command number this particular packet is instructing the module to execute.
    /// </summary>
    public ModuleCommand Command { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Specifies the commands for this module.
/// </summary>
public enum ModuleCommand : byte
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The user has just clicked the Connect button (on form's GUI) and is sending this connect packet.
    /// </summary>
    ClientRequestingConnectionPacket = 0,

}
```

**Explanation for a 'WelcomeModulePacket' class:**

So since I have more than two modules, having a *single* enumeration 'CommandModule' enumerating *every* command for *all* modules, would be a really long enumeration and pretty disorganized. That's why I have a *different* 'ModuleCommand' enumeration for each module.

**Connection Packet**

```
/// <summary>
/// The user has just clicked "Connect" on the Welcome form of the client. The client is now requesting a connection to the server.
/// </summary>
public class ClientRequestingConnectionPacket : WelcomeModulePacket
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

So, you can see how my classes don't only have two layers of inheritance, but *three*.

```
ClientRequestingConnectionPacket : WelcomeModulePacket : Packet
```

The issue with this design is apparent when I store specific packets like 'ClientRequestingConnectionPacket' into a less specific data structure. For example, enqueuing 'ClientRequestingConnectionPacket' into a generic PriorityQueue (for priority sorting, remember how the 'Packet' class has a 'PacketPriority' property). When I dequeue this packet, it is dequeued as a *Packet*, not a *ClientRequestingConnectionPacket*. In this case, since theres only one packet in there, I obviously know that the packet's original type is *ClientRequestingConnectionPacket*, but when I'm storing hundreds of packets in the queue, I don't have any way to know the original specific type to cast it back.

So I made weird additions like adding this property:

```
Type UltimateType { get; set; }
```

to the 'Packet' base class. But I mean, this 'solution' seems really forced and primitive, and I don't believe its a real solution.

So, based on that link to the other StackOverflow question above, am I making that mistake? How do I fix it? What's the term for this called? How should I design my application?

**REVISED QUESTION: What's the appropriate design pattern for the Packet classes?**

Comment: This sounds like the [Factory Pattern.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)  The Factory Pattern will allow you to specify the type of the object at runtime.

Comment: Perhaps consider Composition (and leave the composed type exposed) over Inheritance.

Comment: consider editing your question. It is overly long and it mostly irrelevant information. Tag 'network-programming' doesn't seem at all relevant to your question.

Comment: Why don't you use protobuf or similar for the serialization? Or an existing RPC implementation?

Comment: Because serialization isn't the real issue. Using YAXSerializer gets the job done. I think I've very briefly explored protobuf. It looks promising, but it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GetType` as FishBasketGordo suggests, or you can test the type using `is`

```
if (packet is ClientRequestingConnectionPacket)
{ /* do something */ }
else if (packet is SomeOtherPacket)
....
```

Answer (score 1):

When you deserialize your objects, what's returned when you call `GetType`? If I'm not mistaken, it will be the actual, specific type, not the general, base type. That way you would need to add an additional property to know the actual type.